# How to change audio source in Web audio APi

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I use Web audio Api to spatialize audios, but i cannot find how to simply change the audio file and keep the effects :

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioContext = new AudioContext();


    // the initial audio
 let audioElement = document.getElementById('underwater-source');
    
 let audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
        
 const pannerNode = audioContext.createPanner();
 audioSource.connect(pannerNode);
 pannerNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

I use this function to change the audio file. It work but the panning effect doesn't work anymore

```
function audioSelector(){
    audioElement.pause();
    audioSource.disconnect(pannerNode);
    const a = document.getElementById("audio-select").value;
    audioElement = document.getElementById(`${a}-source`);
    console.log(audioSource.mediaElement)
    audioSource.connect(pannerNode);
    audioElement.play();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a `newAudioSource`?

Comment: I just want to create an playlist

Comment: Can you provide the HTML too?

Comment: i added my HTML

Comment: Ok. Can I ask you why you are using `document.getElementById(a+'-source')` for `a`? I get lost while following your code

Comment: To find the id of the audio tag

Comment: does anyone know how to create a playlist with web audio api?  if possible, just by changing the audio tag associated with the audiosourcenode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the solution

```
 function audioSelector(){
        audioElement.src = document.getElementById("audio-select").value;
        audioElement.play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says any given `HTMLMediaElement` can only ever be connected to a single `MediaElementSourceNode`. But nothing stops you from re-using that `MediaElementSourceNode` every time you need it. You can store it with a `WeakMap` to make sure you're not preventing the garbage collection from cleaning things up once the `HTMLMediaElement` itself is gone.

Your first snippet would turn into something like this:

```js
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const weakMap = new WeakMap();
const audioElement = document.getElementById('fire-source');

let audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

weakMap.set(audioElement, audioSource);

const pannerNode = audioContext.createPanner();

audioSource
    .connect(pannerNode)
    .connect(audioContext.destination);
```

The function which connects another `HTMLMediaElement` would then look like this:

```js
function audioSelector() {
    // Let's disconnect the currently used MediaElementSourceNode first.
    audioSource.disconnect(pannerNode);

    const a = document.getElementById("audio-select").value;
    const selectedAudioElement = document.getElementById(`${a}-source`);

    // Load a possibly stored MediaElementSourceNode.
    audioSource = weakMap.get(audioElement);

    if (audioSource === undefined) {
        // Create a new MediaElementSourceNode for a previously unused HTMLMediaElement.
        audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(selectedAudioElement);

        weakMap.set(selectedAudioElement, audioSource);
    }

    // Connect the new (or re-used) MediaElementSourceNode.
    audioSource.connect(pannerNode);
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution seems to be able to work, but it doesn't. I think it is because the way I've implemented my
 <select  </select>. I added my html code.